# context-aware colors in SVG/PNG

Tags: svg, png

Many technical websites offer a light/dark user option nowadays, e.g., [GitHub](https://github.blog/2020-12-08-new-from-universe-2020-dark-mode-github-sponsors-for-companies-and-more/) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/). While font colors are obviously adapted to the background, this makes it harder for images with transparent background to look good for both modes. For example:

| GitHub light | GitHub dark |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<style>path {fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1.0}</style>
<path d="M 0 100L 100 100L 100 0Z" />
<path d="M 0 100L 100 0L 0 0Z" />
</svg>
```

Is there context-aware color specification for SVGs or PNGs? Other workarounds perhaps?

Comment: Please add a working example. I suspect your shapes are already filled or stroked

Comment: If you intend to use the svg as an image you can add a style attribute to the svg element like `style="background:white"`. To get the negative of the image you can use a css filter. @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){img {filter:invert(1);}}

Comment: I didn't catch that. How would I have use the SVG if not as an image? Where would the media style go?

Comment: You can use the SVG inline. Read more about [how to use svg](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/). In the case you are using the svg as an image you can add the media style to the css for the html document where you are using the image

Comment: This is for using the SVG on GitHub, for example, so I don't think I have any handle on the CSS.